# Dell R710 RAID PERC H700 Foreign Configuration(s) issue

Tags: networking, ssd, raid, raid-5, dell-poweredge

Just getting around to setting up my server from it sitting some 2 years without plugging it in or running it at all.

Now prior to it sitting I did have it running for awhile and I know it does run as it sits today but there seems to be some configuration issue with it now?

[image: error.png]

This R710 that I have is the 6 x 3.5" version. They consist of:

[image]

```
0-256GB SSD         2-Seagate 6TB HDD   4-Seagate 6TB HDD
1-Seagate 6TB HDD   3-Seagate 6TB HDD   5-Blank
```

I am running the above with a H700 raid PCIe card with Cache Memory of 1GB.

Upon startup the lights look like this:

[image]

Drives 1, 2, 3, and 4 are all lite up solid green. However, drive 0 does not have any lights on at all.

I took out the 256GB SSD in drive 0 and hooked it up to my external USB adapter on my other computer and it came up just fine with all the files on it being correct and not corrupted. I also hooked up a regular HDD to drive 0 and it gave me a solid green lite without that error.

The below image is what it looks like when I tested out drive 0 with a 320GB HDD.

[image]

The RAID with the 256GB SSD looks like this:

[image]

So before I do anything on the server I would like an expert on this to let me know what I need to do in order to boot to my Windows Server that's on the 256GB SSD. The 6TB drive(s) have a lot of stuff on them that I do not want to erase or destroyed by losing the raid 5 array.

I tried pressing <kbd>F</kbd> but it didn't seem to do anything but continue on? And it comes up each time I reboot. Sometimes the drive blinks orange really fast and other times its just off. Am I missing something?

Here are some screen shots of the RAID controller config:

[image]

[image]

Oddly enough when I hit F5 (on the VD Mgmt screen) to refresh it starts blinking the 256GB ssd...

It has shown up once.... But then I did a Initialization and I chose OK when I wanted to choose Cancel...Hence I had to clone the SSD with the image I made prior to doing all of this. Ever since doing that it has not shown up on the list.

It was [suggested](https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/2289155-dell-r710-raid-perc-h700-foreign-configuration-s-issue) to create a new VD without Initialization should fix the issue but It doesn't seem to be selectable. Its grayed out.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: What are you trying to achieve exactly?

Comment: Have you checked [here](https://www.dell.com/community/PowerEdge-HDD-SCSI-RAID/Perc-6-i-Foreign-config-on-disk-how-to-clear-a-disk/td-p/3845325)?

Answer (score 0):

Well..... after a long long battle I finally won :)

1. Shutdown.
2. Unplug.
3. Take drive 1,2,3 and 4 out.
4. Go into the RAID config and create a new VD since the ssd shows up finally
   [image: raidfix1.jpg]
5. Steps 1 and 2 again.
6. Place drive 1,2,3 and 4 in.
7. Boot and it should have my original RAID 5 intact.
   [image: raidfix2.jpg]
8. Reboot with your windows server on a bootable usb drive.
9. Proceed to install windows....
   [image: raidfix3.jpg]
10. Once the above step is completed and it counts down to restart be sure to take out the USB.
11. Windows login screen should come up
    [image: raidfix4.jpg]

Wow... that took a lot. I wish i knew what happened that made the SSD not be recognized since all it did was site in storage few a 1 year or so.

But of all of the above I'm most happy to see this
[image]